# foobar2000 Columns UI - Disable editing song titles?

Tags: foobar2000

I keep single clicking the titles in my foobar2000 playlist.

I'm using Columns UI.
Is there any way to disable/lock the titles (and other fields) from being editable?

I'm using it in a live performance situation because it can play gaplessly (foobar2000 for the win - THANKS!), but the editing thing causes some problems for me if I'm not careful.

I could adjust the double click rate on the mouse, I suppose, but this is the only program that I have this problem on.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, do I feel like an idiot.  There is a setting.
Under Preferences > Display > Columns UI >Playlist View > General tab, in the Appearance and Behaviour section, there's an option for "Allow mouse-activated inline editing."  Just had to uncheck it.
I know I looked at that a few times.  In case anyone else has the same vision problem as me, I wanted to document the answer.